# Software for getting all files under a web address/directory for Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec

Is there software for getting all files under a web address/directory for Windows?

Does this kind of software exist?

Answer (score 1):

**[HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)** allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, **building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server** to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

For websites, the hosting server must allow browsing in that directory (so that you can get the list of files). If that feature is turned off, you won't be able to list the files.
You can also connect with FTP using something like [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client).

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure there is a firefox extension that will do what you want. Cant remember what its called unfortunately but it may be worth having a look!

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox addon [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427) might help you.

> ScrapBook is a Firefox extension, which helps you to save Web pages and easily manage collections. Key features are lightness, speed, accuracy and multi-language support. Major features are:
>
> - Save Web page
> - Save snippet of Web page
> - Save Web site
> - Organize the collection in the same way as Bookmarks
> - Full text search and quick filtering search of the collection
> - Editing of the collected Web page
> - Text/HTML edit feature resembling Opera's Notes